# C# Call a method in a new thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am looking for a way to call a method on a new thread (using C#).

For instance, I would like to call `SecondFoo()` on a new thread. However, I would then like to have the thread terminated when `SecondFoo()` finishes.

I have seen several examples of threading in `C#`, but none that apply to this specific scenario where I need the spawned thread to terminate itself. Is this possible?

**How can I force the spawned thread running `Secondfoo()` to terminate upon completion?**

Has anyone come across any examples of this?

Comment: When Secondfoo() returns, the thread it is running on will terminate.  Why do you think it does not?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use the ThreadPool?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

If you actually start a new thread, that thread *will* terminate when the method finishes:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(SecondFoo);
thread.Start();
```

Now `SecondFoo` will be called in the new thread, and the thread will terminate when it completes.

Did you *actually* mean that you wanted the thread to terminate when the method in the *calling* thread completes?

EDIT: Note that starting a thread is a reasonably expensive operation. Do you definitely need a brand *new* thread rather than using a threadpool thread? Consider using [`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx) or (preferrably, if you're using .NET 4) [`TaskFactory.StartNew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew.aspx).

Comment: This is it :-) I was unaware that a thread terminates when there are no more statements to execute. So this is the exact answer I was in need of. Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 72):

Does it really have to be a thread, or can it be a task too?

if so, the easiest way is:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SecondFoo());
```

Comment: or just `Task.Run`

Comment: @Omu still have to ensure that the Tas.Run fits the need as it comes with  a performance hit

Comment: @Omu yes you're right, Task is faster. Task.Run 's performance specifically is what should watch out for . see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038776/will-task-run-make-any-difference-in-performance and https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html

Comment: [StartNew is Dangerous](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), use `Task.Run` instead.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - This answer of mine was posted in 2011 where the context was DotNet3. You're also posting a link to an article from 2013 in 2021. Don't know if updating any of this is still relevant

Comment: Ron I think it's relevant. People are coming here to find code that works. There are not coming to see exhibits in a museum! Take a look at this: [CA2008: Do not create tasks without passing a TaskScheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2008)

Answer (score 12):

Once a thread is started, it is not necessary to retain a reference to the Thread object. The thread continues to execute until the thread procedure ends.

```
new Thread(new ThreadStart(SecondFoo)).Start();
```

Comment: This code actually creates a new thread, NOT a thread-pool thread

Comment: Thanks Alex. After re-reading my answer I was also surprised! Corrected it.

Answer (score 6):

Asynchronous version:

```
private async Task DoAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        //Do something awaitable here
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a special situation that requires a non thread-pool thread, just use a thread pool thread like this:

```
Action secondFooAsync = new Action(SecondFoo);

secondFooAsync.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallback(result =>
      {
         (result.AsyncState as Action).EndInvoke(result); 

      }), secondFooAsync);
```

Gaurantees that EndInvoke is called to take care of the clean up for you.

Comment: I have used beginInvoke before to run a long processing report in a new thread. Here is an MSDN article on BeginInvoke: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score -3):

As far as I understand you need mean terminate as `Thread.Abort()` right? In this case, you can just exit the Foo(). Or you can use [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) to catch the thread.

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(DoWork);

myThread.Abort();

myThread.Start();
```

Process example:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

class PrintProcessClass
{

    private Process myProcess = new Process();
    private int elapsedTime;
    private bool eventHandled;

    // Print a file with any known extension.
    public void PrintDoc(string fileName)
    {

        elapsedTime = 0;
        eventHandled = false;

        try
        {
            // Start a process to print a file and raise an event when done.
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
            myProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";
            myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            myProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);
            myProcess.Start();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred trying to print \"{0}\":" + "\n" + ex.Message, fileName);
            return;
        }

        // Wait for Exited event, but not more than 30 seconds.
        const int SLEEP_AMOUNT = 100;
        while (!eventHandled)
        {
            elapsedTime += SLEEP_AMOUNT;
            if (elapsedTime > 30000)
            {
                break;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(SLEEP_AMOUNT);
        }
    }

    // Handle Exited event and display process information.
    private void myProcess_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        eventHandled = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Exit time:    {0}\r\n" +
            "Exit code:    {1}\r\nElapsed time: {2}", myProcess.ExitTime, myProcess.ExitCode, elapsedTime);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // Verify that an argument has been entered.
        if (args.Length <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a file name.");
            return;
        }

        // Create the process and print the document.
        PrintProcessClass myPrintProcess = new PrintProcessClass();
        myPrintProcess.PrintDoc(args[0]);
    }
}
```