# Using a socket to connect makes program stuck

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm using a Socket to connect to a TCP Server. However, when I try to connect, the whole program freezes. How can I make it so the program doesn't freeze but will still attempt to connect?

That's my connection code.

```
_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
try
{
    _socket.Connect(IP, Port);
}
```

Comment: You should look into running this application on a different thread. This will allow that process to run parallel to the applications process.

Comment: you can use async/await for better responsiveness UI.

Comment: @TheKingDave this question looks like the OP is stuck without any idea how to continue. I doubt OP has tried anything past that.

Comment: OK then I such reading an article such as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Deriving from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014037/c-sharp-call-a-method-in-a-new-thread):

```
Thread thread = new Thread(YourMethodName);
thread.Start();
```

Also, [check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363377/how-do-i-run-a-simple-bit-of-code-in-a-new-thread) to understand how to achieve the result using `BackgroundWorkers`.

*A snippet from the related post:*

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

        // this allows our worker to report progress during work
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

        // what to do in the background thread
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
        delegate(object o, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {
            BackgroundWorker b = o as BackgroundWorker;

            // do some simple processing for 10 seconds
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                // report the progress in percent
                b.ReportProgress(i * 10);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delegate connection logic to [BackgroudWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)  Class. This way you can have atleast your UI thread (assuming win/WPF app) free to take input from user.