# C#: Sending a TCP request then receiving a big file stream as response

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I am trying to do a simple TCP application that will send a request to a server and after that will receive a PDF file which it should process and save to the PC. I have done some research already on this thing but all I come up with is either a program that always listens to some address and port so it can receive a file, or a program that send a request then receives a small response, not a stream. For now I have the following code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileHash = hashLabel.Text;
        IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        var listener = new TcpListener(localAddr, 11000);
        listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            using (var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient())
            using (var stream = client.GetStream())
            using (var output = File.Create("receivedFile.pdf"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client connected. Starting to receive the file");

                // read the file in chunks of 1KB
                var buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendRequest(string fileHash)
    {
        try
        {
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 11000);

            Socket serverSender = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            try
            {
                serverSender.Connect(remoteEP);

                Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}", serverSender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileHash);
                int bytesSent = serverSender.Send(msg);

                serverSender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                serverSender.Close();

            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", ex2.ToString());
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

So my code should at first send a hash to the server when I press a button, then receive the file as a response. The thing I am trying to do is to somehow combine the button1_Click method and the sendRequest() method, but I've found no way to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're trying to do. Why can't you just call sendRequest from within button1_click?

Comment: So, I am trying to send a request to the server, and receive as a response a byte stream. I tried using sendRequest in my button1_click, but if I put it below the "while" the code is unreachable, and if I put it above the while and before I start the listener the program simply freezes, no error given.

Comment: Hmm, not sure why it would freeze. Try calling it above the while but in a separate thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014037/c-sharp-call-a-method-in-a-new-thread

Comment: Your program freezes because the while(true) statement is an endless loop.  You need to set some condition there so that when it becomes false the while loop stops.