# Prevent process from turning unresponsive

Tags: c#, winforms

My program has to do some heavy calculation. The whole process turns unresponsive after a few seconds in cause of the calculation, while the CPU usage stays somewhere around 20% and the memory usage around 100 MB.

Is there a general way to keep a Windows forms app responsive while doing heavy calculations?

Comment: You are creating `531 billion` character arrays??? I'm surprised it doesn't just crash altogether.

Comment: It would really help to define "inactive". Do you mean unresponsive? Or it just literally stops doing anything and CPU usage drops to 0%...I am guessing that you may need to read up a bit on how to keep a Windows forms app responsive when doing long-running work (using async and worker threads) but please update the question with more concrete detail.

Comment: @JustShadow Not the downvoter, but a typical question like this without code will attract down and close votes.  Your answer could attract downvotes, too, since it just has links for an answer.  Tread carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is to just move that heavy calculation to different thread.
Here is a modified example from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/using-threads-and-threading):

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class ServerClass
{
    // The method that will be called when the thread is started.
    public void HeavyCalculation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Heavy Calculation is running on another thread.");

        // Pause for a moment to provide a delay to make
        // threads more apparent.
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Heavy Calculation has ended.");
    }
}

public class App
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ServerClass serverObject = new ServerClass();

        // Create the thread object, passing in the
        // serverObject.InstanceMethod method using a
        // ThreadStart delegate.
        Thread InstanceCaller = new Thread(
            new ThreadStart(serverObject.HeavyCalculation));

        // Start the thread.
        InstanceCaller.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("The Main() thread calls this after "
            + "starting the new InstanceCaller thread.");

    }
}
```

And some more documentation just in case you need:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/using-threads-and-threading
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_multithreading.htm

And a short way of starting a function in thread:
[C# Call a method in a new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014037/c-sharp-call-a-method-in-a-new-thread)